# Russian Caesar cipher

Tags: code-golf, string, cryptography, unicode, encryption

## The objective

Given a Russian text, encrypt it with Caesar cipher with key 16.

## The basic Cyrillic alphabets

The basic Cyrillic alphabets are: (U+0410 – U+042F)

```
АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ
```

By the Caesar cipher, they are mapped to:

```
РСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОП
```

The small letters (U+0430 – U+044F) are also mapped likewise.

Note the absence of `Ё`.

## Rules

1. Ё (U+0401) and ё (U+0451) are not considered basic, and are mapped to Х̈ (U+0425 U+0308) and х̈ (U+0445 U+0308), respectively.
2. Any other characters are preserved.

## Example

The following sentence:

```
В чащах юга жил бы цитрус? Да, но фальшивый экземпляр!
```

Is encrypted to:

```
Т зрйре оур цшы сл жшвагб? Фр, эю дрымиштлщ нъчхьяыпа!
```

Comment: We only have to map `Ё` and `ё` to `Х̈` and `х̈`, right? And not also the reverse from X/x to E/e?

Comment: @Kevin Cruijseen Since Х̈ doesn't exist in Russian, it falls in *don't care* situation.

Comment: Are all non-Cyrillic characters in the input guaranteed to be standard ASCII? (32-126)

Comment: @Arnauld You can assume so.

Comment: Your answer to @KevinCruijssen should probably be included as a short comment in the challenge to make this perfectly clear. (My initial version was converting `x/X` + diaeresis to `E/e` + diaeresis.)

Comment: That's *far* too soon to be accepting a solution.

Comment: test case for Ё/ё: 'Ёжик живёт под ёлочкой' -> 'Х̈цшъ цштх̈в яюф х̈ыюзъющ'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 33 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
63ÝD16^‚Ž4K+ç`‡•2.w2γ•3äçDl‚vy`«:
```

Would be just the first 15 bytes without the edge case of mapping `Ёё` to `Х̈х̈`.

-7 bytes thanks to *@Grimy*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##DYvLSgJhGIZv5WttBI3hok0bd96DWNAiCFoEhrvfzmEn7WSalTo5lR2mpJqaLGhoG893C3Mj07944YHneRcWp2fmZpMkk45a2fFMPjaN3@FELhV5hdi0Y9Nxxpacv4GFdORGXnbeBsVS4ac/mSTURDfwdctuTXSXAb7wSkAoPGlFdJ1Al9XoipanhEP8UWHIl@gqPqFu66aNn7XCu@gOH7zxwiffVu2pGRH2qVLjwD6POOaEOqc0aHJGi3MuuKRNhy4uV/TwuOaGW/rccc8Dj0JZq/8)

**Explanation:**

```python
63Ý              # Push a list in the range [0,63]
   D             # Duplicate it
    16^          # Bitwise-XOR each value with 16: [16..31, 0..15, 48..63, 33..47]
        ‚        # Pair it with the initial [0,63] list we duplicated
         Ž4K     # Push compressed integer 1040
            +    # Add it to each integer in the inner lists
             `   # Push both lists separated to the stack again
              ‡  # Transliterate the characters in the first list to the second list
                 # in the (implicit) input-string
•2.w2γ•          # Push compressed integer 10251061776
       3ä        # Spit it into three parts: [1025,1061,776]
         ç       # Convert each to a character: ["Ё","Х","̈"]
Dl               # Create a lowercase copy: ["ё","х","̈"]
  ‚              # Pair them together: [["Ё","Х","̈"],["ё","х","̈"]]
   v             # Loop over both these lists `y`:
    y`           #  Push the characters of the current list separated to the stack
      «          #  Append the top two together: Х̈/х̈
       :         #  And replace the Ё/ё with Х̈/х̈ in the (modified) input-string
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž4K` is `1040` and `•2.w2γ•` is `10251061776`.

Comment: Undealt with Ё.

Comment: @DannyuNDos Fixed (at the cost of 24 bytes.. >.>)

Comment: The first part can be ``63ÝD16^‚Ž4K+ç`‡`` for -1. It's a shame `.š` doesn't work on cyrillic letters (even though `u` and `l` do), that would save a lot.

Comment: @Grimy Hmm, sounds like something to report as a bug. And thanks for the -1. Nice approach with the XOR 16

Comment: And the second part can be ``•2.w2γ•3äçDl‚vy`«:`` for -6.

Comment: @Grimy Thanks again. :) After I added the `0776` to my compressed integer I thought about using something with `766` at the end with `4ô` or `3ä` as well, but couldn't really get it to work..

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>148 ... 110</s>  108 bytes

*Saved 12 bytes thanks to @Grimy!*

This function applies some maths to the code points.

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/./g,s=>String.fromCharCode(...(n=s.charCodeAt()-304)%80-1?[(n^16*(n>0))+304]:[1060+n%48,776]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LTsJAGEZfZSQhmZF2aCMpxKQQrG/gkmBSS1sxdUraxjV4N3iJxgcpGBXFyyt8/xPVWbj4Nuc7i3Pkn/h5kI0nhanSUVhFbpW73Vxm4STxg5A3ZTM2NNkrsrGKZZSlx96hn3na5VJKrtxcBv@gX3BhblktUe9Ypt0bcLVvO5tcdS0hGpoPtwe25VgNVW91jHbbGQpRBanK0ySUSRrziNfwxOgKJd3oXTC6xwtKhjessGZY0JzRJVZ0SlM6o1mP4RmlwfCNH0bnKLGmW7rW8pLm@GB0h0@84xVf@NXXA003GGb0yPo73q5/EIxqOuAP)

#### How?

For each character in the input string, we define \$n\$ as its code point minus \$304\$.

```
 characters    | code points  | n
---------------+--------------+---------------
 А to Я        | 1040 to 1071 | 736 to 767
 а to я        | 1072 to 1103 | 768 to 799
 Ё             | 1025         | 721
 ё             | 1105         | 801
 ASCII         | 0 to 126     | -304 to -178
```

Then we apply the following logic:

```javascript
// neither 'Ё' nor 'ё'?
n % 80 - 1 ?
  // output a single code point
  [
    // invert the case if this is a Cyrillic character
    (n ^ 16 * (n > 0))
    // and restore the original offset
    + 304
  ]
:
  // output two code points
  [
    // the first one is either 1061 (Х) or 1093 (х)
    1060 + n % 48,
    // the 2nd one is the combining diaeresis
    776
  ]
```

Comment: [110 with some bitwise magic](https://tio.run/##LY1dSsNAGEW3MhaUGZtMO1pSEdIiXYKPpUJIk1iJk5IJPrf@S9WiuJBUUav1Zwv3W1GcBx/uy7kHzlFwEpgwH40LV2fDqIr9yvgdI/NonAZhxBuykTiW7Bf5SCcyzrPj3mGQ96zLpZRc@0aG/2Cv4KKuPLG@03RVt8/1gfI2ue6oVksIV3mD3b5qeqrO9cb2lnDabW8gRBVm2mRpJNMs4TGv4ZHRFUq6sbtgdI8XlAxvWGLFsKAZo0ss6ZQmdEbTLsMTSofhGz@MzlFiRbd0beVnmuGD0R0@8Y5XfOHXXnOarDFM6aFmu38)

Comment: [Easy fix, still 110](https://tio.run/##LY3LSsNAGEZfZSwoMzaZJlZSEdJS@gguS4UQk1iJMyUTXLfepV5QfJCoqNV6eYXvf6I4Cxff5nwHzkF0FJm4GE9KV@m9pE7D2oRdI4tkkkdxwluylTmW7JTFWGUyLfThYD8qBtblUkquQiPjf9AvuXDb3qZY3fJcvzfkatcP1rnqekI0LR9tD30v8JtcrbU3hNPpBCMh6lgro/NE5jrjKW/ggdEFKrqyO2N0ixdUDG9YYMnwRHNG51jQMU3phGY9hkdUDsM3fhidosKSrunSys80xwejG3ziHa/4wq@97mi6wjCj@37Dhv8A)

Comment: @Grimy Would you like to post it as a separate answer?

Comment: No, I'm fine, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 41 bytes

```
T`А-Па-пя-рЯ-Р`Ro
Ё
Х̈
ё
х̈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcq5DcJQFAXR3FU8cn4N9IAowAQEJCAhCrBZjcwuckiI@YDYtwYczK3IOJjoTKfRbbbqeV4LWTq2eMdPC6eIg2MXVtsBccA@SwKtAg2zJM9Zm8Z4TYqGpjlnvHHlzss4KjWNuKunSH3FFWODLxsfvqYBnpemSor5pJSHacaTGxfe/ApaKCr9AQ) Just a transliteration and a fixup of the two special cases. The characters to be transliterated are listed in mirror order so that `Ro` can be used to specify the reverse order for the transliteration.

Comment: seems works without `ё` case [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dco7EsFgGEbhPqv49LIGezAWQKHQMGMsIHGNCWIMNY3aj3ENsoEU511RpDjVc/rtQafbKopGk7XPHueTKfEVcPI5NOs9j9DjmEdFwcY0w2leNjGtuOKMO09S46zYNOWpoQKNFNaMLa5qfPmZxjhSLRSV80UxL9OSNw9ufMhKShRUPG55RMguj6yE3R8)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul That's not a `U+0451` that you've got there...

Comment: ok it was composed character, my bad, this is why it was working

Comment: seems number of bytes not up to date isn't 27

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Unfortunately TIO always assumes I'm using ISO-8859-1 (most Retina programs do) but here I'm using UTF-8 so I have to count it in UTF-8 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-pC -Mutf8 -MUnicode::Normalize=NFD`), 37 bytes (27 chars)

```perl
$_=NFD$_;y;А-я;Р-ЯА-Пр-яа-п
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY67agJRGIT7PMUfsMwpA@IiFoqddqkl6AoL6i5qClOtueiKiZqgtb6BR8VbjPoCFjMvlONJMcwM3xQTuPXKvTGxQjKfzcQKTsvBSHHoYKYwtxFThrZDK5yNwbewC82e1btwgBW0YIMdDoIF@8IOdnxhyFe2U4Ix9J3giJPwDRoHfjCy4yX72As/8YMt1vjF2aIhw9sbfmF9idDG5BKJRZM/P2h6fq1hVJA2KvfULMetPdS8ol9yE4m8X68@Vrxn9//@FQ)

Comment: Does it work in Perl 6?

Comment: I don't know perl 6, 40 bytes ->52 bytes because there was an issue with `ё` instead of `ё` in input

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>236</s> 166 bytes

```
func[s][rejoin collect[foreach c s[keep
case[c =#"Ё"["Х̈ "]c =#"ё"["х̈"]c < #"А"[c]any[c > #"Џ"c < #"ѐ"][(pick[#"А"#"а"]c < #"а")+ to 1 c - 1024 % 32]]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU3LSsNAFN33K05HBEUFW12Jj39wO2QRphOMLUlI4sJdolZTqrYV/QT3o6KtrY8f6OLeL4qTCnrhXjive2LdKg91SzreTumdBEomjoz1cegHUGGno1UqvTDWrjqCQiLbWkc15SZaKuwtCcqFFPQ4LyCcBcEjS3B3XlR4F9YxFFI5bnBqA/sVHohfgYfCkSuRr9py4bLH/IWMWF1DGqJhSzfQ2GxuYxlbTaeaMor9IIUHQXfgKzLcs9sF39ILGdAbTWgGeuI@@JImfMYZn3N@ALonsw76pC/wBRma8TUX1vzMfXoH39CUxvRKH/RtpQFndVH7r3rgHo/Amc2N7ZN8UTOti/IH)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 199 chars, 333 bytes

```php
<?=strtr($argn,array_combine(($s=str_split)(АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяёЁ,2),[...$s(РСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяабвгдежзийклмноп,2),х̈,Х̈ ]));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7JTsJgFEb3PsUvYdEmtQu3aNj5EmpIRSIk2jZtN@6oUigiYHGeR5yHggMgKC/A4rsvZP37BF3c1XdzztGzehBMJadNy7AMIa4YS6qkGIaymkprKws5NSMIcTNcU6a@nLNEAVvw0MA2drCLPezjAIc4wjFOcIoznOMCl7jCNW7QxC3ucI8HPOIJz3jBK97go4U23vGBT3yhgy56@EYfA/zgF0PKk01rtE4FcqhIJXKpTBtUoU2qUo3q5MGWJkVpVpbluClE6iJyo3RRuWEKOSNXQnPksnlRTASZdFZjsTk1lgjQYFSCT2V@DqMa5/iMY7roM7SowqiILtfneYCdZDzSl1gIZlTg5j6vcPlzmyroMapycYdnDDDkU53y42OwmaIuMvLkP023cppqBhMz/w)

Just a string replacement.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>103</s> <s>102</s> 101 bytes

```powershell
-join$(switch -c($args){Ё{'Х̈'}ё{'х̈'}default{[char](2*(($_-band16)-8)*($_-in1040..1103)+$_)}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHtbhJREP2/TzHUa3dv3W2gGmNMjH0PY8i6bAuGUGTX1GTdZMEiUCwNTZ/A2P9b@gEUpS/gjzNPhLOLGp3kJvfOnHvOmZnmwaHfCqp@vb5Se/SCopXz9qDWUFZwWAu9KjmepdzWfqAjtCMTFz/7ZszjyORudqv4e@77ehi98qpu67W1s2VZquy8cRuV0lPtPNNb2bPWKBWfFLe3S6XiY/1IlXUc61VsGLuWQRK2RWTijLiHlAdyusQjXCEl3GKGBeGSh8SfMeMOJ/yJ2y8J50htwg8siY@QYsFfuC/gCQ8xJz7BHaa4wXfcS@mUk4Jp51pZmPhKmHKCuZwbwlIoE@HnfibTzgRvhWwitFe4FK1vnNjCySPCtRgYCu1MwB2hHogHPuYed8XAqZTukRZM0sY/nbXzNu7W3Ux4zB0S2BLXxGMsRL4nbpeY/2dR5pw7Ol4b62TjxoREY8RHlL14KFOaiviIB7mipo/0kKKcRAU2Kf9D0/dCvyJbVeV1uuUHsi5JbMqyd4Ms94CCZt0Nw1pjv5CDNpT1G@d4/ru/LPr5n@8bRmysfgE)

This script takes a splatted string. Unrolled:

```powershell
-join$(
    switch -CaseSensitive ($args){
        Ё{'Х̈'}
        ё{'х̈'}
        default {
            $offset  = 2*(($_ -band 16)-8) # -band is 'Bitwise AND'
            $offset *= ($_ -in 1040..1103) # is basic Cyrillic alphabet?
            [char]($offset+$_)

        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 53 bytes

```
ＦＳ¿⁼Ё↥ι⁺§хХ⁼Ёϊ¿№…А¦ѐι℅⁺℅ι⎇‹↥ιР¹⁶±¹⁶ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY47TsNAEIZ7TjFstSuZIk2aFAhFFJEQRDwOsHI2xpJlm/UaQZcAgaDwiBAHoKE3ICAQHhegmDmRmTwKGGmq@eb7f39XWz/RUVm2EwuyEae523I2jAOpFIRtkKt7uY4yKbArPNhJU2N9nRkZKr43GXSyGeWZXHGNuGUOpKAe3jP5741hD8RPXyhVAxNlZmquJzl/b@o4MMwNmRM0FGqKz9V1rqd9Z@wsZMO2wlhHHO7BtrGxtodyzWSZ/NuLNXg30VSqHqybQDsjK1U1mXn4zB2qWlniDdAZFnTO2wO6wicsAF9whGPABxoAneKIjqhDx9RdBrzFwgP8xC@gEyxwTBfUZ/iRBvgGdInv@IrP@IHffLqmzuJCubQf/QI) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＳ
```

Loop over the characters in the input.

```
¿⁼Ё↥ι
```

If the uppercase is equal to `Ё`...

```
⁺§хХ⁼Ёϊ
```

... then print the appropriate `х` or `Х` with its combining character...

```
¿№…А¦ѐι
```

... otherwise if it's a Cyrillic letter...

```
℅⁺℅ι⎇‹↥ιР¹⁶±¹⁶
```

... do some maths on its ordinal to create the character to output...

```
ι
```

... otherwise output the input character.